# Assigned id with auto-increment

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In Grails I would like to have an id that has a prefix and is autoincremented.

I would have these prefixes: `A` and `B`.

Then I would have a following sequence:

`new MyObject('A').save()` ---> id = A-1

`new MyObject('A').save()` ---> id = A-2

`new MyObject('B').save()` ---> id = A-3

and so on... Is it possible to combine `assigned` generator with `auto-increment`?

Comment: What's the underlying DB?

Comment: @mikew, it is MySQL.

Comment: Do you have the notion of sequences in MySQL like Oracle? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm#ADMIN11792 You could set the domain strategy to assigned, pull the value from the sequence before saving and prefix the letter then save

Comment: Interesting idea. Have ever done it in Grails. (Of course, I'll have a look but to hear about an experience would be nice. )

Answer (score 1):

Answer is Oracle specific but gives general idea.

Create a sequence in DB:

```
create sequence MY_SEQ minvalue 1 maxvalue 9999999 start with 1 increment by 1;
```

Then in Grails:

```
class MyService {

    def dataSource

    def save( params ) {
        def myDom = new MyDomain( params )
        myDom.id = generateId()
        myDom.save()
    }

    def generateId() {
        def db
        try {
            db = Sql.newInstance( dataSource )
        "A-${db.firstRow( 'SELECT MY_SEQ.NEXTVAL NEXT_ID FROM DUAL' ).NEXT_ID}"
        }
        finally {
            db?.close()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the primary key as an integer and add a getter method to derive the A1, B1 value. It's not a good idea to mess with primary keys like you're proposing.

Comment: thx but we need a descriptive id. Currently we have `{A|B}-{randomlyGeneratedLong()}`.

Comment: That's not the job of a primary key.  A primary key is used to uniquely identify a database row.  If anything, what you want is a composite key, but GORM discourages them.  

More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7383118/511250).